# Exception while running Spark program with SQL context in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to run a simple Spark scala program built with Maven

Below is the source code:

```
 case class Person(name:String,age:Int)


object parquetoperations {
  def main(args:Array[String]){

    val sparkconf=new SparkConf().setAppName("spark1").setMaster("local")
    val sc=new SparkContext(sparkconf);
    val sqlContext= new SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._
    val peopleRDD = sc.textFile(args(0));
    val peopleDF=peopleRDD.map(_.split(",")).map(attributes=>Person(attributes(0),attributes(1).trim.toInt)).toDF()
    peopleDF.createOrReplaceTempView("people")
    val adultsDF=sqlContext.sql("select * from people where age>18")
    //adultsDF.map(x => "Name: "+x.getAs[String]("name")+ " age is: "+x.getAs[Int]("age")).show();

  }
}
```

and below are the maven dependencies I have.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
<version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0-M4</version>
</dependency>
```

It throws the below error. Tried to debug in various ways with no luck

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   scala.Predef$.$scope()Lscala/xml/TopScope$;

Looks like this is an error related to loading the spark web ui

Answer (score 0):

All your dependencies are on Scala 2.10, but your **scala-xml** dependency is on Scala 2.11.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0-M4</version>
</dependency>
```

Btw, unless you really have a strong reason to do so, I would suggest you move to Scala 2.11.8. Everything is so much better with 2.11 compared to 2.10.

Comment: I tried with scala 2.11 as well. Faced the same error

Comment: go over your pom and replace all the 2.10 with 2.11 and try again. As I said, you have 2.11 in one place and 2.10 in others. You need to be consistent.

Comment: One more thing, Scala XML was part of Scala up to 2.10, so all the XML code is included in 2.10, there is no need for you to add the **scala-xml** dependency (if you decide to use 2.10).